# Google OAuth 2 Callback URL

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I have a simple PHP website that I would like to implement G OAuth 2 authentication.

The website consist of an index.php page and a profile.php page that shows a table from the database with a query.

I am trying to add a button on index.php where the user will authenticate using G Oauth and will be redirected to profile.php

I created a project on Google APIs got my credentials and set the callback URL.

The code I used is provided by Google here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web

I do get the login button on index.php but when I click on it refresh and says: Your are logged in instead of redirecting.

Could you please give me some hints what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The example code don't seems to design to redirecting you anywhere.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question, not as a link. External content may be changed or removed in time, making the question meaningless to other developers on the future.